# Batch environement variables woes

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables

I have no problem with process-level variables, such as:

```
Set a=ABC
Echo '%a%'
> 'ABC'
```

And I understand why persistent variables, being set in the registry (at one of three possible locations), are not available in the current session:

```
Setx a=ABC
Echo '%a%'
> '%a%'
[Open a new command window:]
Echo '%a%'
> 'ABC'
```

This works the same when the first portion is in a script, and the last two lines occur in a Command window (cmd). However, when I set (setx) a persistent variable in a script, and then run another script to read it, the results are wildly unpredictable to me. For instance, the first time I run the following script, I expect it to set the variable (but not Echo it), while on all subsequent runs, since the variable is set previous to calling the script, %a% should have the value ABC:

```
Echo '%a%'
Setx a ABC
Echo '%a%'
Pause
```

Unfortunately, even on the second run both Echo statements return an empty value (''). A new command window will return the expected value ('ABC'), as I noted before.

To make things worse for me, SOMETIMES I can access a previously stored variable's value - but then I can't change it. I suspect that in these instances I am accessing the variable from another environment (System vs User vs Machine), but I can't seem to understand this.

Why can I not access the persistent variable from a script? How should I be writing the script so it can?

Answer (score 0):

When initiating from `cmd` the help. `setx /?` a specific area specifies:

> NOTE: 1) SETX writes variables to the master environment in the registry.
>
> 2) On a local system, variables created or modified by this tool
>            will be available in future command windows but not in the
>            current CMD.exe command window.

You therefore need to close the current `cmd` window and start a new instance in order to load the new or modified environment variable from the master environment.

However as per your comments you simply want to store the environment variables once off for other scripts to access. therefore this:

```
if not defined aa setx aa ABC & exit
echo %aa%
pause
```

when you run it the first time, will set the variable and exit, if the variable is not yet defined, when you run the script the second time, it will not set it, as it now finds the variable exists.

if however you want to do something in the script the first time it is run as well with variable `%aa%` then simply set the temp variable as well.

```
if not defined aa setx aa ABC & set aa=ABC
echo %aa%
pause
```

So first time you run the above, it will set a locally and in the environment, but the 2nd time you start it, it will skip the first line as `%a%` is found in the environment.

We can then look at editing existing variables as well:

```
if not defined aa setx aa ABC & set "aa=ABC"
if not "%aa%" == "NEW_VALUE" setx aa NEW_VALUE & set "aa=NEW_VALUE"
echo %aa%
pause
```

Same principal, but now we check the value as well to see if it contains the modified value required.

Comment: OK, how do I "close the current cmd window and start a new instance" from the script? I have just verified that logging out and back in to Windows will allow the script to show the values saved (in some past session), but that's more than a batch script can do.

Comment: Correct. So `setx a ABC` then `exit` and open `cmd` again and run `echo %a%`

Comment: You do not have to log out of windows, just close `cmd.exe` and open one again.

Comment: I can't get that to work. It sounds like you are telling me to use commands in a manually-opened cmd window, not a script.

If I exit the script and rerun it, as I said in the beginning, that doesn't work.

I also tried to open a subsidiary batch file ("cmd /k EchoValue.bat"), but that also cannot report the newly set value.

Comment: ok, so what is the reason you need to store those values in the environment permanently? Perhaps I can help with that instead. `setx` is not meant to run in scripts to update environment variables each time it runs

Comment: I need to be able to call those variables from another program. For the record, I am not trying to use setx "to update environment variables each time it runs"; I am trying to use it to set up persistent values that later scripts can call. Normally, the variable will never again change.

Comment: ok, so then you are fine. If you run a once of script that does the set, then you are good to go. Give me 10 minutes to update my answer.

Comment: Since 'a' is already defined from running the script above, I changed it to 'aa'. With ONLY that change, the script exits on the first line, every single time I run it.

Comment: seems you did not change the `aa` in the setx and `aa` in if defined. I updated the code with the new `aa` requirement across all 3 examples, please try as is.

Comment: I did, but you didn't, after the setx command in line 2 of "editing existing variables" code: [if not "%aa%" == "NEW_VALUE" setx a NEW_VALUE & set "aa=NEW_VALUE"]. My code is (with ';' for newlines): if not defined aa setx aa ABCD & set aa=ABCD ; echo %aa% ; pause . After I run this script, I run another script that is echo '%aa%' ; pause and the output is '' (the variable is not picked up). Same as always.

Comment: are you running that new script from `cmd` or by double click?

Comment: Double-click. I am giving up, and creating a (usually) hidden file at the root of the C-drive. The script will be run with Admin permissions, anyway, so no matter where it is run  (once) it can be accessed by other scripts.

Comment: Instead I'll use (again, running with elevated permission):    If Not Exist "C:\.VarName" Echo Value >"C:\.VarName" ; Attrib +r +h +s "C:\.VarName" ; Type "C:\.VarName" ; Pause

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. This works perfectly well if implemented correctly.

Comment: No, it does not work. I am copy-pasting your code, running it once, and then running a second script to read the variable - which it can't. Your script ALWAYS has a local variable named 'aa', which may be why you think it works, but no later script will retrieve the persistent variable 'aa' until a logoff/logon cycle. Try running "echo '%aa%' ; pause" from a batch file script (not from the cmd window prompt!).